# Rails redirection after JSON 3xx loses authentication headers

Tags: redirect, rspec, http-headers, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

Following the rspec tutorials, I discovered

```
expect(response).to redirect_to()
follow_redirect!
```

Problem is my request was authenticated using JSON Web Token Auth.
WHen doing the redirection I am losing those extra headers that were passed to the `get` request, hence getting an unauthorized 401 response on the redirect.

The solution would be to explicitely make a `get response.headers['Location']` but I was surprised to see almost little information concerning this ? Or am I using the wrong way to set headers in rspec request specs ?

In my rspec I am using the following to make a request

`def my_request
   post my_resource_path, params: payload, headers: auth_headers
end`